# Magento resize image in xml feed

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, product

We are producing with a php file a .xml feed for one of our partners. At this moment we have the main image with the code:

```
$product_data['image_link']=Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product'.$product->getImage();
```

When we run the loop we get the image with:

```
 <image_link>
<![CDATA[<?php echo $product_data['image_link'] ?>]]>
</image_link>
```

For this partner we also need a image with a smaller size and want to give it a width or height. Does anyone know how to change the code to give it a size?

Answer (score 0):

Just try with this,

```
<image_link>
<![CDATA[<?php echo '<img src="'.$product_data['image_link'].'" width="200" height="200" />'; ?>]]>
</image_link>
```

Or

You change your image size with magento, like this,

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(90,60); ?>" width="90" height="60" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
```

or, By your method ,

```
$product_data['image_link']=Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product'.$product->getImage()->resize(90,60);
```

**Update**
Actually I dont know how did you write your code,
I assume that you will probably load product collection like this,

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProduct()->getId());
```

Then resize your wish, like this,

```
$image = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(38, 38);
```

Then use resized image like this,

```
<image_link>
<![CDATA[<?php echo '<img src="'.$product_data['image_link'].'" />'; ?>]]>
</image_link>
```

Comment: Hi Elavarasan, Thanks for your reply, when we place this code in the php we get the result with the widht and height, but we would like to get the smaller image, like in the category. There you see a image that is already 150px and with the url domain/media/catalog/product/cache/2/small_image/150x/602f0fa2c1f0d1ba5e241f914e856ff9/y/1/y1325.jpg. Can we also get that picture without cache or are the small images always in the cache?

Comment: I have updated my answer..Please check out.When you resize() function it resize image from original image and displays resized image..not from cache..So dont worry about that..

Comment: Thanks for your update, when I use the last method $product_data['image_link']=Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product'.$product->getImage()->resize(90,60); we get a error message when we run the loop. We get the message Fatal error: Call to a member function resize() on a non-object in /home/domain/public_html/feeds/kledingnl.php on line 213. Do you have an idea how to call it?

Comment: We load all our images with $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection() , but still not get it to work with your last part. Do you know if you can call it on a different way with that code?